# Extract records from huge Json File

Tags: json, filter

I have a huge json file with 5500 records. The file display three levels  as you see in the code and i want  to extract all the records with a define level . How can i do that?

```
{
"Dictionary": {
    "Words": [
        {
            "name": "fdfafd",
            "level": "easy"
        },
        {
            "name": "dfdaf",
            "level": "medium"
        },
        {
            "name": "ddsss",
            "level": "difficult"
        },
          {
            "name": "fdfafd",
            "level": "easy"
        },
        {
            "name": "dfdfadaf",
            "level": "medium"
        },
        {
            "name": "ddddsss",
            "level": "difficult"
        }

    ]
}
```

}

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code, please.

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its case of deep serialization. You need right object structure to accommodate it.

Such as following (add getters and setters and default constructor in case you overload constructor):

```
Class Dictionary{
    List<Words> words;
    Class Words {
        String name;
        String level;
    }
}
```

While initialize serializer use something like :

```
    jsonSerializer.include("words");
    jsonSerializer.include("words.*");
```